# Custom inherited button in items control, content not being set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

(I'm using WPF and the MVVM pattern)

Firstly, I have inherited from the Button control to create my own custom button. This is because I want this button to have some added properties:

```
public class RangeButton : Button
{
    public Rank CardARank { get; set; }
    public Rank CardBRank { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuited { get; set; }
    public string ButtonContent { get; set; }

    public RangeButton(int i, int j, bool suited)
    {
        CardARank = GetRankFromInt(i);
        CardBRank = GetRankFromInt(j);
        IsSuited = suited;
        SetButtonContent();
    }

    public RangeButton()
    {
    }

    private Rank GetRankFromInt(int x)
    {
        return (Rank) x;
    }

    private void SetButtonContent()
    {
        ButtonContent = StaticGameHelpers.GetRangeSegmentString(CardARank, CardBRank, IsSuited);
    }
}
```

I initialise a list of RangeButton's in my view model, each of it's properties are being properly set - I end up with a list of 169 RangeButtons:

```
public List<RangeButton> RangeButtons
    {
        get { return _rangeButtons; }
        set
        {
            _rangeButtons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RangeButtons");
        }
    }
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding RangeButtons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <inheritedControls:RangeButton  Width="70" Height="50" Margin="3">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ButtonContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </inheritedControls:RangeButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="13" Rows="13"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

All 169 buttons are being displayed but each button is completely blank, with no content. Also, the width, height and margin properites are being ignored which leads me to believe there is a problem with my xaml but i can't quite figure it out.

I realise there are some similar questions asked like this, but none are using a custom inherited button. Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: If you're initializing a list of RangeButtons in your view model, then it's not MVVM anymore. According to MVVM, the view model should not be aware of the view. Though you're forcing the view model to contain some view items (buttons).

Comment: Have you tried using an `ObservableCollection` or `ConcurrentBag` for your list?  This may be why it's not refreshing, it's binding to a simple old `List`.  Just a guess :)

Comment: @dymanoid Ahh yes, you are right - thanks for pointing that out. Do you think a better approach would be to have a List of custom objects such as List<RangeObject> in my vm which will contain the same properties as my RangeButton - then in my xaml use this as the items source but re-template each item as a button?

Comment: This is the right direction. And I doubt you need to subclass the `Button`. You can either apply a `ControlTemplate` in XAML or use attached properties (in your custom class).

Comment: @DanRayson Just tried it and no luck. I think I need a whole new approach as pointed out by dymanoid

Comment: Besides what has need said about your approach not being MVVM, you might just remove `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` from the Content Binding. `RelativeSource Self` means the binding would look for a ButtonContent property in the ContentControl, which of course doesn't exist. You would also have to remove `inheritedControls:RangeButton` from your DataTemplate, because the bound ButtonContent property already contains a RangeButton.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some advice from @dymanoid I took a different approach. I scrapped the whole inheritting from the button control idea and simply created a custom object 'RangeSegment' which would replace my RangeButton failure. In my VM I stored a list of RangeSegments and used these as the ItemsSource for my ItemsControl. Then inside the Datatemplate for each item, I added a Button, with the content property bound the properties in each RangeSegment